# What are Measures and Dimensions in Cubes

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, ssas, business-intelligence, cube

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server Business  Intelligence and `Analysis Service` (but I've been programming for years with SQL Server). Can any one describe Measures and Dimensions in Cubes in simple words (If it's possible with images)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Think about a **process** or **event** that you want to analyze.

Let's say you were building [Lougle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Tub_Time_Machine) Analytics, and want to analyze visits (as opposed to single-page requests) to your site. Visiting a website is a process.

A **fact table** represents a process or event you want to analyze, in this case it is a list of site visits. You can have as many fact tables as you want, one per process or event.

What things might be useful to you in analyzing site visits?

- Information about the web browser (brand, screen resolution, ...)
- Information about the user (country, state, city, ISP, based on their IP address)
- Information about when the visit started (year, quarter, month, week, day)
- The duration of the visit
- The referring page, landing page, and exit page (title, url path)
- The number of pages visited during the visit

Technically, you could put this all into one table - as you would in Excel, but that'd get real big real fast, so we'll do ONE level of normalization. Dimensional design is often just "put everything you need for an analysis in one big table", and then normalize out one level.

So your fact table will look like this:

```
web_browser_key          bigint
ip_address_key           bigint
start_date_key           int
referring_page_key       bigint
landing_page_key         bigint
exit_page_key            bigint
duration_seconds         int
number_of_pages_visited  int
```

It has a bunch of key values that refer to values in other tables†, and two non-keys. The non-keys are numeric values and are called **Measures**. Can you take the average of the web browser brand name? No, so it's a dimension. Can you take the average of the visit duration? Yes, so it's a measure.

The other tables are called **Dimension** tables, and the `ip_address` dimension table might look like this:

```
ip_address_key  bigserial primary key, /* use meaningless surrogate keys */
ip_address      inet unique,
country         text,
division        text,
locality        text,
latitude        numeric(8,6),
longitude       numeric(9,6)
```

Notice that it is not normalized: country could be derived from city (locality). However in a data warehouse, we care about *facilitating analysis* first. By facilitating analysis, I mean [avoiding deep joins](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278837/how-can-i-argue-convincingly-against-duplicating-database-columns/278846#278846).

Notice that some of the data in the dimension table is *hierarchical*: country > division > locality. Your OLAP server (hopefully) understands hierarchies to support drill-down operations.

A logical **Cube** is just the *collection of Dimensions and Measures* that you are working with. Unlike a Rubik's cube, it can have more than 3 dimensions. Just think of a dimension as a column in your data set.

**OLAP** is *a set of operations* you can do against a data set, such a pivoting, slicing, dicing, drilling. Think of Excel PivotTables. An **OLAP Server** facilitates OLAP operations.

† usually without foreign keys

Comment: I liked the explanation with an example, but small issue - there's no mention of a `city` in your schemas, so when you say `country could be derived from city` I'm not positive what you mean.

Comment: @mmcrae 'locality' is the generic name for city/town/village

Comment: *"Can you take the average of the web browser brand name? No, so it's a dimension"* But you can take the count to get an idea of how many user access your website through that browser. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(data_warehouse)) states that *"a measure is a property on which calculations (e.g., sum, count, average, minimum, maximum) can be made."*. Does this mean that all columns (including dimensions) are measures?

Answer (score 13):

In the image below which is an example of a basic Star Schema. The Dimensions are the Dim_Tables.

These are generally the values that you want to analyse the data by. So you want to look at a particular product sales, in a particular country, over a particular date range.

In the fact_sales table you have just the one Measure which is Units_Sold.

Measures (at the simplest level) are just things you that want to aggregate when analyzing based on criteria in the dimensions.

[image: Basic Star Schema]

Comment: It seems this image comes from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema. You should mention it.